# How to access the method in zeep

Tags: python, zeep

I am trying the below code but I get the zeep.exceptions.Fault: null
error

```
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth
from requests import Session
session = Session()
username = ""
password = ""
url = ""
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username,password)
transport = Transport(session=session)
client = Client(url,transport=transport)
client.service.CI_Z_SP_PERS_DTL_CI_G(EMPLID="001670")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the following to the question: (1) What are you trying to achieve? (2) The full Traceback error message. (3) What should be the expected output (4) Is `CI_Z_SP_PERS_DTL_CI_G` a valid SOAP service, (please consult the official docs for the SOAP API)?

Comment: Traceback (most recentcall):File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/proxy.py", line 42, in __call__ self._op_name, args, kwargs) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 132, in send return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 194, in process_reply return self.process_error(doc, operation) File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 299, in process_error detail=fault_node.find('detail')) zeep.exceptions.Fault: null

Comment: i read official docs of zeep and i have applied all the http connection methods i am getting the same error in all methods

Comment: I've just added few steps to debug this error as an answer. Please post what you get  from the `print` statements(when the exception is caught), in your question.

Comment: try:
...      client = Client(url,transport=transport)
...      client.service.CI_Z_SP_PERS_DTL_CI_G(EMPLID="001670")
... except Exception as e:
...      print(e.message)
exception message is null only

Comment: after try and except block i get exception message as null only

Comment: What is the output for the other `print` statements? You should consider upgrading to the latest version of zeep as some bugs are fixed with every version upgrade. I also noticed that your Python env is 2.7. Its best to use Python 3.x as Python 2.7 support has been phasing out for many libraries, although this may not be the sole reason for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but the following way  could help capture the source of the error in your code. To get the actual error causing line/snippet in your code, you can use a try/except block and catch the error:

```
#<---code--->
try:
    session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(username,password)
    transport = Transport(session=session)
    client = Client(url,transport=transport)
    client.service.CI_Z_SP_PERS_DTL_CI_G(EMPLID="001670")
except zeep.exceptions.Fault as fault:
    print fault.message
    print fault.code
    print fault.actor
```

OR

```
except zeep.exceptions.Fault as fault:
    print fault.__dict__
```

This will help debug where exactly the error is occuring.

Comment: Please share exact output of all print statements.

Comment: It is the output of print fault.__dict__                                                        {'message': 'null', 'code': 'SOAP-ENV:Server', 'subcodes': None, 'detail': <Element detail at 0x7f7e5978acf8>, 'actor': None}